# Join element in an array by two

Tags: ruby, arrays, join

My array looks like this:

`arr = ["object 1", 3, "object 2", 6]`

How can I create the expected output below? Is there a simple way using `join`?

`object 1 (x3), object 2 (x6).`

Comment: I think you need a `hash` for data like that.

Comment: Hash wont woke as some of the keys might be the same but the value would always be different.

Comment: Then, instead of a hash, use an array with the "key" followed by the sub-array containing the "values". Using a flat array would work but it's better to organize and group the data when possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no *logical* conversion from your array to your string so I think you should rethink it all.
But you could do

```
arr.each_slice(2). # get every two elements
    map { |top| "#{top.first} (x#{top.last})" }.  # create a string for each pair
    join(', ')    # join them by a comma.
# => "object 1 (x3), object 2 (x6)"
```

Comment: Im not really sure what any of this is doing, could you maybe explain a bit more? I get the join ....

Comment: @KyleAdams what about now ?

Comment: You can use `map` this way: `.map { |a, b| "#{a} (x#{b})" }`